# InfiniteScroll (PaulIrish) and Isotope and jQuery and Paths

Tags: jquery, infinite-scroll

Desperately trying to get isotope and infinitescroll to work together...

Isotope works on its own fine. When I introduce IS, isotope keeps working, but I get jquery errors (in Chrome dev tools) which I don't quite understand and, of course, IS does not work.

The error at the moment is: "Navigation selector not found", so I think this might be to do with my path...

I think it might be 2 things, 1. My misunderstanding of the correct syntax; 2. the path for IS...

My URL structure is: http://mysite.org/tag-gal/tag1/tag2/tag3/page1

So the link for the next page is: http://mysite.org/tag-gal/tag1/tag2/tag3/page2

These URLs are interpretted within .htaccess to rewrite to: http://mysite.org/tag-gal/index.php?t=/tag1/tag2/tag3/&$p=1

below is some code that I am trying to use:

Obviously I include jquery, isotope and infinitescroll js files.

```
  <div id="photos">
     <div class="item thumb">
         <a class="fancybox" rel="gallery1" href="img/15_pv.jpg"><img src="img/15_th.jpg"></a>
     </div>
  </div>
  <div class="page_nav">
    <a href="http://mysite.org/tag-gal/page2">Next</a>
  </div>


  <script type="text/javascript">
          $(document).ready(function() {
            $(".fancybox").fancybox({
            openEffect  : 'none',
              closeEffect   : 'none'
            });
          });
  </script>


  <script>
    var $container = $('#photos');
    $(function(){
      $container.imagesLoaded( function(){
        $container.isotope({
          layoutMode: 'masonry',
          itemSelector: '.item'
        });
      });
    });
  </script>

  <script>
    $(function(){
    $("#photos").infinitescroll({
        navSelector : "div.page_nav",
        Selector : "div.page_nav a",
        itemSelector : "#photos div.item",
        debug: true,
        pathParse: ['/page', '']
      },

      // trigger Isotope as a callback 
      function( newElements ) {

        $newElems.imagesLoaded(function() {
          $container.isotope( 'appended', $newElems );
        });
      }
    );
    });
  </script>
```

Hope someone can help.

Thanks.

Comment: OK, well simple fix it seems.
`Selector > nextSelector`
Now just to get isotope to arrange items properly when newitems are loaded...